# I cannot update data via Jquery popup

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have an gridview that displays data, on click of test button, shows a popup with data of clicked row. When I changed value of textboxes record was not modified. How can fix this issue ???

Comment: This problem isn't reproducible as presented. Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The browser will only send form elements which have a `name` attribute, so my guess is that your problem is that Your TextBox's don't have name:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAutor" name="txtAutor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /> //Not familiar with asp, so I'm not sure if this is the correct way to set the name attr of the TextBox
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:
`Id: <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />`

- I think you should use `<asp:TextBox ID="lblId" runat="server" name="id"></asp:TextBox>`

`Autor: <asp:TextBox ID="txtAutor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
Viti: <asp:TextBox ID="txtViti" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

- These two input elements need `name` attribute to pass the value in form.